# bundle installしようとしたところpermission deniedエラーになる

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`$bundle install`を実行したところpermission deniedとなりgemをインストールできません。
↓
エラー内容

```
The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies.....
Using rake 13.0.1
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.5
Using i18n 1.7.0
Using minitest 5.13.0
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using tzinfo 1.2.5
Using activesupport 5.2.3
Using builder 3.2.3
Using erubi 1.9.0
Using mini_portile2 2.4.0
Fetching nokogiri 1.10.5
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_file_s_rename -
(/Users/username/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/cache/nokogiri-1.10.5.gem,
/Users/username/rails/taskleaf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/cache/nokogiri-1.10.5.gem)
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.10.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.10.5' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before
bundling.

In Gemfile:
  rails was resolved to 5.2.3, which depends on
    actioncable was resolved to 5.2.3, which depends on
      actionpack was resolved to 5.2.3, which depends on
        actionview was resolved to 5.2.3, which depends on
          rails-dom-testing was resolved to 2.0.3, which depends on
            nokogiri
```

エラーメッセージの記載通り、
`gem install nokogiri -v '1.10.5' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`を実行するもコマンド自体動きませんでした。

(https://rubygems.org/gems/nokogiri)　にて「nokogiri」を検索　
 ↓
`gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.10', '>= 1.10.5’`をGemfileに貼り付け
`$ gem install nokogiri`　実行
↓

```
Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.5/LICENSE-DEPENDENCIES.md
```

Comment: `sudo rm -rf vendor/bundle`でそのrailsアプリ用のgemを一度全部消してから、`bundle install`するとどうなるでしょうか？　gemファイル自体かそのインストール先フォルダのPermissionが何かで変わってしまっている場合なら、これでインストールしなおせば直ると思います。

Comment: ご教授いただいたとおり`sudo rm -rf vendor/bundle`でgemを一括削除した後`bundle install`で無事サーバーを再起動することができました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

gemのインストールでパーミッションエラーが出る時は以前どこかで`sudo`をつけて`bundle`や`gem`の操作をしてしまったためにファイルの上書き権限がない事が原因になってる場合が多いです。

`rbenv`再インストールして`gem`も入れ直すのが一番簡単な解決方法だと思います。

Comment: ironsandさんのご指摘の通り、`sudo`で`gem`の操作をしていた為、ユーザーでファイルの上書きができなくなっておりました。ご教授いただきありがとうございました。

Comment: 解決したようでなによりです。解決済みのチェックを押してもらえますと一覧で見た時に解決済みだとすぐに分かって便利なので、できればよろしくお願いします。